# Passing an array of objects to the controller using JSON

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5

My array is like this:

```
Array[2]
 0: Object
        StockNo: "1"
        InvoiceNo: "1234"
        MaterialName: "MaterialName1"
        PONo: "1234"
        PRNo: "2124"
        Project: "ProjectName"
        Qty: "1"
        Remarks: "Test"
        Supplier: "SupplierName"
        TotalAmount: "23"
        Type: "2"
        Unit: "23"

  1: Object 
        StockNo: "2"      
        InvoiceNo: "1234"
        MaterialName: "MaterialName2"
        PONo: "1234"
        PRNo: "2124"
        Project: "ProjectName2"
        Qty: "1"
        Remarks: "Test"
        Supplier: "SupplierName"
        TotalAmount: "23"
        Type: "2"
        Unit: "23"
```

and this 2 array is inside in variable named **"inventoryList"**
and I want this to pass in my Controller. I used

> JSON.stringify(inventoryList)

but it's not working.

Here's my script:

```
function addSomething() {
    var dateReceived = $('#DateReceived').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/MyController/Create",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: {
            'dateReceived': dateReceived,
            'rrList': JSON.stringify(inventoryList)
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.errorMessage != '') {
                alert(data.errorMessage);
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = '/MyController/Index';
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: $_POST var is empty or what?

Comment: @Daimos, are you sure you are talking about asp.net-mvc-5 as it's marked with tags?

Comment: @Diamos it's not  PHP..

Answer (score 0):

change JSON object to

```
inventoryList=JSON.stringify({ 'inventoryList': inventoryList});
```

Then in your controller

```
public void Create(DateTime dateReceived,List<object> inventoryList)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i see that should work.

What seems to me is the content type of sending data should be `application/json` and async should not be set to false because it destroys the behavior of ajax.

So my suggestions are:

```
function addSomething() {
    var dateReceived = $('#DateReceived').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/MyController/Create",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json', // <----add the content type
        //async: true, // you can remove it because default is true.
        data: {
            'dateReceived': dateReceived,
            'rrList': JSON.stringify(inventoryList)
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.errorMessage != '') {
                alert(data.errorMessage);
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = '/MyController/Index';
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. it's working. My problem right now is passing the Datetime thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ajax Json</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Well Come</h1>
        <hr>
        <div id="data">Response Add Hear...!!!</div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $obj1={"StockNo":"1","InvoiceNo":"1123","MaterialName":"MaterialName1"};
            $obj2={"StockNo":"1","InvoiceNo":"1124","MaterialName":"MaterialName2"};
            $obj_array=[];
            $obj_array.push($obj1);
            $obj_array.push($obj2);
            $obj_array=JSON.stringify($obj_array);
            $.ajax({
                url:'test.php',
                method:'post',
                async:false,
                data:{"test":$obj_array},
                success:function(data){
                    $("#data").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

**Server File**

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($_REQUEST['test']));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```